# Orange Pi PC не подключается внешний жесткий диск

Tags: ubuntu, orange-pi

Имеется Orange Pi PC(v1.2) и ЖД 2.5" в боксе с выходом в USB3.0 и USB2.0(наверное, доп. питание, но работает и без него), Lubuntu 14. Так вот при подключении данного ЖД к данному миниПК ничего не происходит. На миг загорается светодиод на ЖД и тухнет. И все. /var/log/syslog пуст

Comment: Подключал на порт матери или на передней панели? В винде при том же подключении работает? Очень похоже на нехватку питания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Было такое на CubieBord'е. Возможно порты не вытягивают питание по току. Как вариант попробовать USB hub c внешним питанием, опять же родной блок питания может не "выдавать" нужный ампераж. Для меня на "Кубике" все решилось заменой блока питания платы с 5В 1,5А на 5В 2,5А.